# Length of the median of a triangle

Tags: geometry

Given a triangle of sides 11,60 and 61 units. What is the length of the median to the side of length 61 units from its opposite vertex? I solved it using Stewards theorem and obtained a value 61/2. My question is whether  can it be calculated in some other way.

Comment: Hint: 11, 60, 61 is a pythagorean triple, so you have a right triangle.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: as I typed this @DreiCleaner wrote his comment.

You have a right triangle. Now, knowing this, because you are getting the median for the hypotenuse side, it is noticeable that you have split the hypotenuse in 2 and as a result by drawing a lines parallel to one of the other sides from the midpoint of the hypotenuse you will get a similar right triangle to 11, 60, 61 triangle (with side lengths that are all half the side lengths of the original triangle). This can be seen by this picture: [image]

Thus, flipping the similar triangle over the side it doesn't share with the larger triangle we can see that the median is half the length of the hypotenuse of the larger triangle which is $\frac{61}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking in a different direction from @justaguy.

There is a theorem that tells us that when you draw the circumcircle of a right triangle, the hypotenuse of the triangle will be a diameter of the circle. (This is probably more commonly stated by saying that an angle with its vertex on a circle cuts off an arc of twice the angle measure. Thus a $90$ degree angle cuts off a $180$ degree arc, which is a semicircle).

The midpoint of the hypotenuse is therefore the center of the circle. So you can easily see that any radius must be $\frac{61}{2}$. And the median from the right angle to the midpoint of the $61$ unit side is a radius.

Comment: Thanks . Excellent logic.

Answer (score 0):

The Apollonius's theorem, also called the median theorem, relates the length of a median of a triangle to the lengths of its sides. Specifically, in any triangle ABC, if AD is a median,
$${\displaystyle |AB|^{2}+|AC|^{2}=2(|AD|^{2}+|BD|^{2})}$$